# Font of swiss licence plates

Tags: font-identification

I am looking for the font used on swiss car plates. I know the reality is a bit confusing, since there has been several version of the font. Also it appears that some plates that exist are legal, but incorrect. That is due to the fact that plates are delivered by cantons, so there is variations...

Here two exemples:

[image]

[image]

[Link to image on Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plaque_d%27immatriculation_suisse#/media/File:Swiss_utilitary_reg_4229.jpg)

They are slightly different. It is probably two different versions of the same font. I noticed that the "0" is kind off egg shaped, which is very different from the font used is neighboring EU states. The "8" is also recognizable, with a smaller upper loop.

thanks for any help

Comment: I found this on google http://www.leewardpro.com/articles/licplatefonts/font-numberplate-switz.html

Comment: I saw it too, but it say "A close replica of Switzerland’s number plate lettering" and it is not free. If my company has to buy it, then I would prefer the right one.

Comment: There might not be a "right one".  All the number plates look to be die stamped/embossed, prehaps for security reasons. If so, there might not be a digital font.  Perhaps a special/authorised machine might be needed to stamp the letters into the plate?  Who knows!  Not all lettering is downloadable as a digital font file.

Comment: You are probably right. The plates are around since before digitalisation. Also there is several plate making companies, so there might be variations in quality.

Comment: UPDATE: I received documents from one plate-making company. It is not a digital font, I can confirm. It looks like engineering from the 60's made on a drawing board, with all spaces and measurements described. I like that a lot actually.

Answer (score 5):

These are not fonts in the traditional sense where you can just download them digitally to use. The characters are imprints from plate-making dies made specifically for the plate-making machines that produce them.

You will NEVER find a 100% accutare version of this unless you fly over to Switzerland and manage to source and bring back the dies.

That being said, there are a number of typefaces available that either were modeled after or resemble various types of license plates.

A good clone is [Numberplate Switzerland  |  2000–2004, Stephan Müller, commercial](http://www.leewardpro.com/articles/licplatefonts/font-numberplate-switz.html)

[image]

You can even test it out [here](https://lineto.com/The%20Fonts/Font%20Categories/Headline%20Fonts/Numberplate/). That could solve some of your problems.

It's also worth noting:

> Switzerland’s font seems to show multiple influences. Some characters
>   are based on DIN 1451, such as C, G, O, and Q, which retain DIN’s
>   circular rounds, while other characters with rounded shapes such as B,
>   D, P, and R feature more squarish rounds, similar to France or
>   Britain’s alphabets. Some of the numbers, however, exhibit oval-shaped
>   curves akin to, but a bit different from, those seen in American
>   license plates, while the odd zero character with its base wider than
>   its top recalls the capital O from Germany’s FE Schrift. Definitely a
>   mixed brew.

[Here's a German truetype variant that I stumbled across.](http://www.autokennzeichen.info/kennzeichen-schriftart.htm?cc_yes=1&cc_time=1513702085)

Additionally you could just ask the [ASTRA Authority](https://www.astra.admin.ch/astra/de/home.html), maybe they'd be helpful since ["The ASTRA determines the typeface and dimensions for letters and numbers"](https://www.admin.ch/opc/de/classified-compilation/19760247/index.html#a94).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I go to Switzerland almost everyday. I will try to get some info from a plate-making company. If it does not work i will use this replica font,